# MVC Html.BeginForm using Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I'm using MVC areas and on a view that's in an area called "Test" I would like to have a form that posts to the following method:

```
area: Security
controller: AccountController
method: logon
```

How can I make this happen with Html.BeginForm? Can it be done?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Try this:

```
Html.BeginForm("logon", "Account", new {area="Security"})
```

Answer (score 96):

For those of you that want to know how to get it to work with the default mvc4 template

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", new { area = ""}, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
```

Comment: +1 for the *additional* anonymous type with 'area', rather than adding 'area' to the anonymous type with 'id', as I had tried.

Answer (score 7):

Try specifying the area, controller, action as RouteValues

```
@using (Html.BeginForm( new { area = "security", controller = "account", action = "logon" } ))
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this for area with HTML Attributes

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(
      "Course", 
      "Assign", 
      new { area = "School" }, 
      FormMethod.Get, 
      new { @class = "form_section", id = "form_course" })) 
{

   ...

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", action = "/Account/LogOff" }))
                {@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <a class="signout" href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">logout</a>
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

For Ajax BeginForm we can use this

```
Ajax.BeginForm("IndexSearch", "Upload", new { area = "CapacityPlan" }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = updateTarget }, new { id = "search-form", role = "search" })
```